# 4 different Matlab functions to estimate the PDF of data give 4 different results

Tags: matlab, gaussian, noise, probability-density

I might be stuck in some details, but I am stuck in at seemingly operation. I have a set of data `gaussian_noise` (representing white noise with `mean = mu, and std_dev = sigma`) and I want to plot the PDF of this data. The values of `gaussian_noise` are in the range of [-0.0155; 0.0155]. I used several methods which all give me different plots. All of them not corresponding to the theoretical PDF of a gaussian distribution with `mean = mu and st_dev = sigma`. Do you know what I am missing? Normalization? But `ksdensity` apparently returns a normalized result. Here are some examples of what I am doing and the plots:

```
[pdf_empir, sample_data] = ksdensity(gaussian_noise);
figure; plot(sample_data, pdf_empir);
```

[image: Plot of ksdensity]

When I change the bandwidth of `ksdensity` I get a smooth, continuous curve but agian with different values

[image: Plot of ksdensity with bandwidth 0.002]

By using `histogramm`

```
figure; histogram(gaussian_noise,'Normalization','pdf');
```

[image: Plot of histogramm's output]

Of course I can smooth the curve to obtain a continuous PDF but the point that bothers me is the fact that the function values (y-axis) are all different.

By using `histfit`

```
figure; histfit(gaussian_noise)
```

[image: Plot of histfit's PDF]

The theoretical PDF of a gaussian distribution with `mean = 0` and `sigma = 0.0027`, evaluated for the data range `x_range = [-0.0155; 0.0155]` and for 10000 instances looks like (obtained with `normpdf`)

[image: Theoretical Gaussian PDF]

The peak is at 146.9 which corresponds to the theoretical `1/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi))`.

Apparently, I am doing something wrong by applying above methods. I guess, I need to do some normalization. But when I divide by `length(gaussian_noise)`, since it is a constant, I again obtain different values with the different methods.

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?
Appreciate your ideas and comments.

Comment: I think the answer to most of this is: you are missing theory, specially theory of discrete statistics/mathematics. You don't seem to be doing anything inherently wrong, just you do not know exactly what are the implications of using a method or the other.

Comment: Thank you @Ander Biguri for editting my post. How can I make pictures to appear in the post as you did? As I added the figures to the post they were automatically placed as link references at the end of the post

Comment: You dont have the reputation yet, you will get it once you get some points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fundamental thing here is that it's not the peaks of the distributions which need to agree, but the area under them. Also if the distribution is normalised then the area should be equal to 1.

In each of the plotting methods above the "bin width" are of different sizes which cause the values in each bin to change in order to preserve the area under the curve.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Palmer. I certainly forgot the bin width factor which in this case is essential. Depite this, if I integrate with `trapz` over any of the results I should get a value of 1, shouldn't I? However, I get totally random values of e.g. 9*10^4 and so on. Even when I normalize by `trapz(pdf_empir)/length(x_range)` I get 9. Is there another function I should use to calculate the integral? Thank you.

Comment: If your bins are constant length then try AREA = bin_width * trapz(pdf_empir)